# a good resource to study about 2 classification ways?

Tags: classification, neural-networks, references

One of my friends has asked me a question and because I haven't been involved with clustering a lot, I decided to ask his question here. He says that:

> There are two classification ways :  **C4.5** and **jordan/Elman ANNs**.
>   Do you know of any good resource which has covered these 3 ways
>   comprehensively?

He wants to know about the concept of these two ways and their algorithm. In fact he wants to understand these ways intuitively and get the purpose of them. Do you of any good book or another resource which has explained the concept extensively?

Comment: None of those are clustering/unsupervised algorithms!

Instead, they're all classification methods (they take some labeled data and learn how to label other, unlabeled data). Furthermore C4.5 and J48 are the same algorithm! J48 is a java implementation of Quinlin's C4.5 algorithm.

Comment: @MattKrause ok do you know any resource? Any good neural networks book that has comprehensively explained the `jordan/Elman networks`? And any resource which has explained the Quinlin's C4.5 algorithm? Is there any relation between the latter one and fuzzy c-means clustering?

Answer (score 1):

These are **classification** algorithms.

You can find detailed information e.g. in the Weka book. Look for "decision trees". Or in fact, pretty much any other textbook on machine learning.